# dubbo use fastjson2 Serialize error autotype not support

Tags: fastjson, apache-dubbo

java.io.IOException: org.apache.dubbo.common.serialize.SerializationException: com.alibaba.fastjson2.JSONException: auotype not support
when provider return a generics dto,the server throw this exception
when I use dubbo 3.2.5, find this problem,how to fix it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.